# Pre-populate user email from facebook API

Tags: javascript, facebook, jsp, facebook-login

I am trying to implement social login on my website. I am requesting user-email from facebook API and want to pre-populate email field in one of the form with that email. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. I am new to programming so asked such a newbie question. I passed a hidden input parameter in form for email and assigned the value of email that I received from facebook to the input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.10). After you get the email from the response, you can then store it into a server session, pass it to the next web page where your forms are located or anything you want to do with it

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
       console.log('email: ' + response.email);
     });
    } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
}, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
```

Comment: So I am using Facebook SDK for facebook login on a JSP page. So how to store the email in server session and pass it on to next page to prepopulate email field?